# How to use hash (#) on urls in chaplin.js like backbone used to do?

Tags: backbone.js, chaplinjs

let's say that I have two "pages" (endpoints) on a chaplin.js site

**the routes:**

```
match('', 'first_controller#show');
match('second_view', 'second_controller#show');
```

**and two links:**

```
<a href="{{#url "first_controller#show" }}{{/url}}">Go to home</a>
<a href="{{#url "second_controller#show" }}{{/url}}">Go to Second</a>
```

the generated urls are "correct":

```
mysite.com/something/     (home)
mysite.com/something/second_view  (second view)
```

(notice that I'm not on the root of the site). When I start the application at "home" and then click the "Go to second" link i get correctly redirected to the second view, everything gets tendered correctly and the url on the browser changes to `mysite.com/something/second_view`

But then I cannot refresh the navigator since my webserver will try to reach a `second_view` folder instead, and I'll get a 404.

What i need is to **always** generate the urls using a `#` like in backbone, something like `mysite.com/something/#/second_view`.

BTW: that last link works but chaplin deletes the `#` (like a redirect)

Maybe I need to configure something? or change something on the ùrl`helper, I couldn't find anything in the docs. Any Ideas??

Thxs

Comment: BTW, that's called a hash.

Comment: you can't just use a falltrough ?

Comment: @user1737909 not sure what u mean by "falltrough" :P

Comment: accept any kind of url you don't recognize just to let it go to your index

Comment: noup... can't do that :P. I'd really need the hash in the url. There must be a way to configure chaplin to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone itself allows this functionality out of the box, through

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: false})
```

(the default)

You can see the [startHistory call here](https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin/blob/baca4567bf94dcb0ed3690b1774f326eea52665e/src/chaplin/lib/router.coffee#L41).
You just have to pass this options object as a second parameter to `initRouter` in your `Application` :

```
this.initRouter(routes, {pushState: false});
```

Comment: did u mean "pushState" on `initRouter()`?

Comment: pushState on initRouter gets me closer... now i dont get redirected on the browser, but the links generated with the `url` helper dont use the hash.. Do I need to create another helper?

Comment: Ah, it may. I think you should file an issue, and use `{root: '/#!'}` for now

Comment: @pleasedontbelong, the expectation on Chaplin's side is that the hash is mostly a fallback for browsers that don't support the HTML5 History API (`pushState`). The server should still be able to deal with the routes, too. Are you hosting a Chaplin app from a purely static file server?

Comment: @knuton well actually it wasn't a static file server so I ended up using the pushState and redirecting everything  (server side) to the root of the chaplin app.. I had a few problems setting pushState to False and i had to finish this quickly :P